# Revert a commit on remote but not in local

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to revert last commit on remote but not in local?
I have a commit that's not yet ready to be pushed, but i want to keep it on my local rep.

Comment: If it is not yet ready to be pushed, why do you need to revert it on remote? How did it get there?

Comment: I pushed it but mistake, and now I want to cancel that

Comment: If you are not opposed to re-writing remote history, you could make a new local branch with the stuff you want to keep, then reset your tracking branch to how it should look like without the stuff you did not want to push and force-update the remote branch to match it.

Comment: Always work on a local branch. This will give you a possibility to do actions on master without hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest option would be to create a separate branch with your said commit and explicitly `revert` the commit on the main branch and push the changes.

```
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git revert <commit_id>
git push origin master
```

When your commit is ready to be released again, you can revert the revert commit.

Other approach would be to again create a separate branch, and reset the HEAD on the main branch to the previous commit and force push the changes. You should only go for this option, if you're not sharing the branch with anybody or you explicitly made sure that it's not going to affect others.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can push the parent of the remote branch’s tip to the remote branch:

```
git fetch
git push -f origin origin/master^:master
```

where `origin` is the remote and `master` is the branch. Or, if you’re already synced up and on the relevant branch, it’s just

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

assuming you intend to remove the commit and not create a revert commit (since that’s probably just going to be an annoyance down the road).

Answer (score 1):

The best option here is probably to `git revert` the commit on the remote:

```
git revert <SHA-1 of bad commit>
```

Then, just push normally and the state of the remote would just be your latest commit.

If you need to remove the bad commit immediately, then consider the following:

```
# from your local branch
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
git revert <SHA-1 of bad commit>
git push origin your_branch
git stash apply
git commit -m 'your latest commit'
```

This takes your latest commit and resets it back to the stage.  Then, we can stash those staged changes.  Note that this essentially moves your latest commit from your branch to the stash.  With your local branch clean, you may `git revert` the bad commit, push, and then apply the stash to get your changes back.